# How does a clinet know which CA a server's certificate uses when doing https handshake?

Tags: https

I was asked in an interview a couple of days ago, and I can't find the answer on Internel.
So I was hoping someone can answer it. Thanks very much

Comment: Isn't it mentioned in the "Issued By" in the certificate?

Comment: Oh, I see. I found the answer on wikipedia, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#TLS/SSL_server_certificate),  As @Am_I_Helpful said, issuer's name can be found on certificate, and the client will perform [Certification path validation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_path_validation_algorithm) to validate the certificate.